# Can't fire ouibounce.js modal on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to set up a page with a modal window which fires on either the mouse existing the window or on the click of a link.

Firing on exit is ok using Ouibounce:
http://carlsednaoui.github.io/ouibounce/

The documentation on the Ouibounce API suggests I should also be able to fire the modal via a click.

I have changed the link in the above example, giving it an id of #modal_button but I can't get it to fire the window:

```
  // if you want to use the 'fire' or 'disable' fn,
  // you need to save OuiBounce to an object
  var _ouibounce = ouibounce(document.getElementById('ouibounce-modal'), {
    aggressive: true,
    timer: 0,
    callback: function() { console.log('ouibounce fired!'); }
  });


  $('#modal_button').on('click', function() {
    $('#ouibounce-modal').fire();
  });



  $('body').on('click', function() {
    $('#ouibounce-modal').hide();
  });


  $('#ouibounce-modal .modal-footer').on('click', function() {
    $('#ouibounce-modal').hide();
  });

  $('#ouibounce-modal .modal').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
```

I set up a jsfiddle here which does the same thing. 
http://jsfiddle.net/fr7k3s6f/

(for some reason the 'hide" on the body event doesn't work in the jsfiddle)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use your object _ouibounce to call the fire() function on:

```
_ouibounce.fire();
```

and not the jQuery object. And it needs to be a global object if you define it at jQuery.ready(), so no "var" before. But i think this is a bug in the current version (0.0.10).

I hope this helps.